# Do we need to configure Local Disk Failover for Auxiliary databases when they are in a cluster

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7

This is a basic question. We have a 3 node cluster configured and we are planning to get down the Bootstrap host for maintenance. We want the application to be up and running even when one of the node is down.

Do we need to configure Local disk failover for Security,Schemas,Modules and Triggers databases i.e having the replica of Forest on bootstrap host on other hosts?

Or they share the same Security and modules documents on all the servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the node that hosts a forest is taken down, the content of that forest becomes unavailable. At that point, yes, you want to have local disk failover. It works the same for Security, Schemas, etc., as it does for content databases.

Comment: Thank you. So, I must create replicas for security forest(security-rep1 and security-rep2) on other hosts and attach it to the database.Finally Host 2 : Security Database has Security-rep1 forest   and Host 3 has Security-rep2  forest. I am confused as I could see the same documents on Security Forest on all the hosts even without configuring Local HA.

Comment: If I understand, you attached the forest to the db.  You need to instead configure it as a replica as shown here:  [link](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/config-local-failover#chapter)

Comment: The documents in the Security forest are visible in the same way that all the documents in a content database are visible on every node in a group, even though each document only actually exists in one forest (plus replicas).